# Burninate the "store" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

- [store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/store) — 21 tagged, 5 this year

  > *no tag wiki/excerpt*

This extremely broad tag seems to be on a variety of questions where existing, more specific tags serve a much better, specific purpose.

The store tag seems to have been used to mean both the [ios-appstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-appstore) and the [mac-appstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-appstore), as well as the [itunes-store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itunes-store) and [ibookstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibookstore), and not forgetting the physical [apple-store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-store).

Should it be burninated?

Comment: Yes.
On the same assumptions as the [PC tag question][1]


  [1]: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/burninate-the-pc-tag

Comment: Wow, never seen that happen before on an answer! (automated "trivial answer converted to comment")

Comment: @stuffe we need that on the main site. So much mod time converting to comments...so much...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Burn it. Burn it with fire.

Comment: Will do! At least there's not many questions tagged with it. I'll still spread it out though to not flood the front page.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside why bother it should get deleted and then I doubt anyone would enter it as when you type store as a tag it will list the actual store tags

Comment: Any objections to my synonym proposal? It needs votes up or down either way...

Answer (score 2):

Please vote for the synonym I created if you feel this will help prevent a generic store tag from resurfacing after this clean up effort.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/apple-store/synonyms

Comment: I don't have the score for a +1 on the synonym :(

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Oh wow - if 26k doesn't cut it, it might just be elected mods that can weigh in...

Comment: I need a score of 5 on the tag to vote for synonyms I think; the error message could be improved if this is the case.